# Тег input поисковой строки ЯндексКартинки (ya.ru/images) не сохраняет введенный запрос в атрибуте value

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath

На сайте ЯндексКартинки (ya.ru/images) ввожу любой поисковый запрос.
Нахожу тег input поисковой строки, в нем есть атрибут value, но в нем не сохраняется введенный запрос (атрибут пуст). При этом запрос в самой поисковой строке отображается. Не могу понять как такое возможно, откуда браузер берет эти данные; и как введенную строку собственной найти, где она хранится. Каких то других атрибутов или тегов, хранящих значение не нашел. Причем это происходит не всегда, а только если сразу зайти на ya.ru/images, если же сначала ввести запрос в обычном поиске ya.ru а затем перейти в поиск по картинке - то значение сохраняется (но тоже не всегда).